# Chrome font smoothness

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts

Is there anyway to make font look smooth on Chrome, Windows 7?
Large fonts and sometimes even italic look very rough and jagged.

EDIT: ClearType is on.

Thank you.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: What OS? Which version of Chrome? Do you mean you want (but don't have) regular text "antialiasing" (blurring) or sub-pixel "antialiasing" (rainbows), or is there a different problem? Italics *should* look *very* jagged without "antialiasing", but this should be less pronounced with large fonts.

Comment: Windows 7, since Chrome 1. Not blurry, just jagged edges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve font appearance in google chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I do have ClearType on. (Read question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there appears to be a lot of confusion and misunderstanding about this bug! Even within the actual Chromium Team at Google there seems to be confusion. Lots of info in this Chromium forum linked below. Essentially it seems the problem is how Chrome renders fonts in Windows so there is not much you can do until Google resolves this. And it has NOTHING to do with ClearType being off -- the common response to this issue!

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692

Also, there is a note in that forum that for some folks a workaround was actually putting the SVG font first. This of course is only applicable if you are using @font-face rule (not a Google / Typekit font) and the font has an SVG version.

UPDATE: finally this bug in Chrome will be fixed in Chrome 37, due around the start of September. So after that this should be a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your @font-face, try shedding the WOFF line (lose the SVG line too, it's not worth the size).

For some fonts, the WOFF files will make rendering horrendously bad.  Just the EOT for IE and TTF for every other browser.

Comment: To that, all I can say is: "In YOUR @font-face!".

Answer (score 0):

Try [MacType](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/). It can smooth the fonts on Chrome and on Windows 7.